Authenticate Salesforce community user using rest api in connected App
I am building a custom login page in react native mobile app to allow user to login into salesforce exp site. Upon form submission I want salesforce community user (not an individual user) to authenticate in salesforce experience cloud site by calling some salesforce REST APIs using connected App.
It should be more of a implicit behavior where after passing username and password, api should respond with user_access_token.
Is it this behavior possible for community users in salesforce
or any further refined approach i can use ?

Just an update, There is feature limitation with community user in salesforce as of today. Its does not allow salesforce to feature as IDP for community users. No implicit behavior is available to allow community user to login.
